# Ubuntu 18.04 service not working for start/stop/restart actions and not printing the echo statemetns

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, services

I have a custom script and I configured it as a service in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, when I run it with

```
service process start
```

it neither invokes or prints the echo statement. Whereas it works with CentOs and event Ubuntu 16.04, 14 versions.

Answer (score 0):

You might be lacking the aliases for controlling systemd. This aliases were created in some distributions of linux as a way to easy the transition.

You are better off learning and using systemctl to control it.
Learn more here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html

In your case the proper command is:

```
~# systemctl start process
```

Basically the same as you would using "service" but first come the action (enable, disable, status, start, stop, restart) and then the service name.